Having issues trying to install a DBD::mysql client for perl on Server 2022
I'm trying to get DBD::mysql installed under strawberry perl. I've been slowly working my way through a number of configuration issues. I've got to the point where I'm trying to run gmake.  I'm stumped about this one particular error. Here is the command that gets run by the makefile.
g++ mysql.def -o blib\arch\auto\DBD\mysql\mysql.xs.dll -shared -s -L"c:\mysql\install\lib" -L"c:\mysql\install\lib\debug" -L"C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\STRAWB~1\c\lib" -L"C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -L"C:\STRAWB~1\c\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\13.2.0" dbdimp.o mysql.o socket.o   "C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\libperl540.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmoldname.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libkernel32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libuser32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libgdi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinspool.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomdlg32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libadvapi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libshell32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libole32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\liboleaut32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libnetapi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libuuid.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libws2_32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmpr.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinmm.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libversion.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbc32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbccp32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomctl32.a" -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base

I get a lot of undefined references in this compile.
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: dbdimp.o: in function `mysql_dr_connect':
C:/Perl64/cpan/build/DBD-mysql-5.010-0/dbdimp.c:1208:(.text+0xa74): undefined reference to `mysql_server_init'
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Perl64/cpan/build/DBD-mysql-5.010-0/dbdimp.c:1209:(.text+0xa81): undefined reference to `mysql_init'

I ran dependencywalker across the mysql.dll file that is contained in the c:\mysql\install\lib folder which is referenced in the first line above as
-L”c:\mysql\install\lib”
That file showed that it contained those functions mysql_server_init  and mysql_init and all the rest of the missing references.
Is that the right way to define it in the command line or am I missing something else entirely? I'm not a C programmer so please give as much detail as you can.

Re "I ran dependencywalker across the mysql.dll file", I don't see anything referencing that file. Shouldn't there be something like -lmysql?

Maybe I am missing something, but why are you not using the tool that comes with Strawberry perl: cpan? Do you need to compile your own version?

FWIW, Strawberry Perl comes with a lot of things already compiled because the coordination between all the different parts is not trivial. If you wanted to compile something new, you need to use the same tools and setup that Strawberry Perl does. The cpan tool (and other CPAN tools) should handle all of that for you.
